# How come Shopify recognizes my local currency with Tor browser!? (no log-in, no address entered)

Tags: anonymity, javascript

I recently stumbled upon this online store https://www.faunapparel.com/ (which is a Shopify plateform).  Basically, they're detecting your local currency (either CAD, USD, EUR, GBP or AUD) when you're entering the website and they charge you in that currency **even if you select a different currency in the dropdown** (they only display the currency you select, but they will still charge you in the **currency they determined for you**).

So how come do they know my currency is CAD even with the Tor browser? (I know they know because there's a message on top of the home page that says "Free shipping for orders of $50**CAD** or more").  The Tor browser is run with the medium security setting (in order to access the necessary Javascript) and the exit server was in Netherlands.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAD is the default and changing the currency in the drop down doesn't affect the displayed message at all.

The site doesn't know, it's purely a coincidence if it is accurately depicting your currency.

I am not in Canada or using a Candian locale and it gives me exactly the same message.[image: currency choice]

Comment: So weird, since they are located in California!

Comment: The server its hosted on appears to be in Canada (according to its whois) so that might be why :) https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-23-227-32-0-1/pft?s=23.227.38.64 Are you thinking of the wrong CA? :P Canada not California?

Comment: No no :p https://www.faunapparel.com/pages/policies

  Please send all returns to:

19749 Dearborn St
Chatsworth CA 91311
United States